# Record the entry and exit of employees

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

My friends, I am doing the personnel management project and I had a problem controlling the entry and exit of personnel. I register the entry and exit of personnel through the personnel ID, but I do not know what mechanism I should design to register the exit. Control the entry and exit of the system in SQL Server. And the code I wrote is to store employee logins. It should be noted that the model I use is the repository generic and unit of Work model.

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = int.Parse(txtIDPersonnel.Text);          

        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            ArrivalsAndDepartures save = new ArrivalsAndDepartures();
           
            save.IDPersonnel = id;
            save.ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now;
            db.GenericArrivalsAndDepartures.Insert(save);                                                         
            db.Save();              
            
        }
    }
```

The table definition for the times recording looks like:

[image]

The screen where the user enters their ID looks like:

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: You might want to include a question in your "question". Consider using `int.TryParse` (instead of `int.Parse`); someone mistyped s number is hardly _exceptional_

Comment: what do you mean by exit time? when will you have this value? if later then you need to update the record

Comment: I mean the time of departure when the employee intends to leave and the date and time of her departure is recorded

Comment: _when the employee intends to leave_ You need to be more precise. How does anyone know when an employee "intends to leave"? Are you thinking of a work schedule where each person is assigned a shift that begins and ends at planned point of time? Seems you might need more help defining your requirements **before** you start implementation.

Comment: This program has other parts as well, and all of these parts have been completed, and only the part of registering the entry and exit of employees remains, and this presence and absence are done using a barcode reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every one of these systems I've worked on the exit time has been nullable (able to be left blank). When we are registering an arrival, we leave the exit time blank. This can be used for queries like "how many employees have a filled-in entry time and a blank exit time?", and these are hence the employees who are at work right now. By recording the time of entry we can also minus it off the current time and see how many hours they have been at work.

Later when the employee comes and clicks the "sign out" button and gives their ID, you can search the table for records for that ID where the entry time is set and the exit time is blank; that is the record you need to update with the current time as the exit time. You also have the option then to detect that the employee didn't sign in when they entered and correct it (perhaps ask them what time they arrived?) so you should always only ever have one record with a blank exit time. Having more than one blank exit time per employee is also an error that you can detect/when they next sign in you can check if they still have an open record because they forgot to sign out last time

At the end of the week/month the sign in/out times can be used for calculating hours present and potentially the pay owed. It's probably important to have the "correcting sign in and sign out" times being supervisor-only to prevent incorrect information being registered by employees

Comment: Can you give me a sample of this code?

Comment: I'm afraid that StackOverflow isn't a free coding service, and to some extents it's even pushing it to ask for design advice because we cannot design *your* system for you. I deliberately kept to talking about just what I've experienced in terms of structure for the majority of access control systems I've worked on; it's up to you to design and implement but we can help you with any specific problems you get with the code when you do. Take a look at the code you have, how you might locate a user record based on the ID plus the null exit time, how you'd update the exit time and then save it

Comment: The key to my tablet is something else, and I come and go through the personnel ID. How do I find a relationship between the two that can be used to record departure time?

Comment: Edit the question to tell us more about the design of your database

Comment: Did you look at the photo I asked with the question ??

Comment: Gotta be honest; I read straight over it/didn't notice. We tend to discourage images unless they're asked for but an image of a database design diagram is useful. I'll edit the question to inline it so it's no longer a link(new users cannot embed)..  it does look like you have all the necessary info to do the lookups I recommend - finding open sessions with `select * from arrivalsanddepartures where idpersonnel = @x and exittime is null` or if you're using an orm then `arrivalsanddepartures.Where(t => t.Idpersonnel == x && t.ExitTime == null)`

Comment: thanks a lot. But I must say that I have already used this code that you said. My problem is how to save the departure time

Comment: If you were using EF it would be something like `var activeRecord = context.ArrivalsAndDepartures.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Idpersonnel == x && t.ExitTime == null);` followed by `if(activeRecord != null) activeRecord.ExitTime = DateTime.UtcNow;` and saving it with `context.SaveChanges()`, but you haven't really gone into any detail on how you do database access; in essence the answer is "get the record, set the time, save the change"

Comment: I have tried this method before. You see, the problem is that the Primary Key is "RegistrationID" and this way I can update the table record and record the exit time.

Comment: No one ever said that the only way to search a table is via lookup on the primary key. Index the Idpersonnel+exittime

Comment: Thank you so much for all the guidance you gave me. I was able to solve my problem myself.